# How to click and enter values in dynamic text area in protractor?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am using protractor for angular 4 application e2e testing.

In the application code, I am not able to find the unique id, class, name, text for the textarea which is placed in my application.

Please help me to get unique xpath.

```
<textarea maxlength="250" pinputtextarea="" required="" ng-reflect-rows="2" 
ng-reflect-cols="50" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-maxlength="250" 
ng-reflect-model="Test description 2" class="ui-inputtext ui-corner-all 
ui-state-default ui-widget ng-pristine ui-state-filled ng-valid ng-touched"
rows="2" cols="50">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Post your code first

Comment: <textarea maxlength="250" pinputtextarea="" required="" ng-reflect-rows="2" ng-reflect-cols="50" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-maxlength="250" ng-reflect-model="Test description 2" class="ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget ng-pristine ui-state-filled ng-valid ng-touched" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>

Comment: In order to get _unique_ xpath, we should have the whole HTML of the page...

Answer (score 1):

We would need the whole HTML of the page to give a precise xPath.

However, if you are using Chrome, you can literally just open the dev console, right click on the textarea HTML element you have indicated above, and click "copy xPath", which will put the unique xPath on your clipboard.

That being said, I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want this test to be reliable it's probably not likely to be a good idea to use the full xPath, since any change to the HTML on the page would break the test.

[image: xPath in chrome]